# Start default music app in Android and play file

Tags: android, url, android-mediaplayer

I have app where I have url of media file.
I wish if I could start Music and Video app and play file.

Is there any chance to do that.
I dont want to write my own media player app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an ACTION_VIEW intent with the path to your media file and include the type of media you want to play.

```
String audioPath = "path/to/audio.mp3";

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

// set the data and type, for movies this would be video/*
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(audioPath), "audio/*");
getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

You don't have to set the type, but I would suggest doing so. Setting the type will limit the activities to activities that know how to handle the given type.